# Software for compressing files in Raspbian

Tags: pi-2, backup, software-recommendation

I am trying to compress a folder of many files into a tar.xz format. Does anyone know of some good software that does this job in Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 2 B?

Comment: Did you try something along this line https://askubuntu.com/q/92328/606336 ?

Comment: No, I had not. I didn't know that there was a command to compress files. Thanks @Ghanima!

Comment: It should work out of the box on Raspbian too.

Comment: I would think `tar` is the command you're looking for

Comment: Tacking on "in Rasbian [sic] on a Raspberry Pi 2 B" generally does not make a question more on-topic that it would be without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855850/create-a-tar-xz-in-one-command) might shed a little light on the command itself that you will want to use.

> Use the -J compression option for xz.
>
> ```
> tar cfJ <archive.tar.xz> <files>
> ```